# render scene such that each pixel represents .1 mm square

Tags: 3d-printing

I would like to render a side shot of my model, such that each pixel is .1 mm.  This corresponds to the smallest vertical resolution of my 3D printer.  The scene would of course need to be rendered in ortho mode.  The question I'm having is how can I get the camera and output resolution lined up so that I can choose between .1 .2 and .3 mm pixel sizes?  thanks!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken 1:1 10000x10000px by ortho scale of 1 should be .1mm per pixel (1000mm/10000px). Or 1000x1000px by ortho scale of 0.1 (100mm/1000px).